# MariaDB: how to reduce ibdata file size

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, ibdata

I found that My MariaDB's ibdata file keep increasing.
So, I've searched for this, and found that `innodb_file_per_table` should be set as 1.
but, my DBMS's configuration has already set as 1;

Why ibdata file size keep increasing and what else should I do for this.

These below are my dbms info.

```
DBMS: MariaDB
engine: InnoDB Engine
version: 10.3

** my.cnf **
innodb_file_per_table=ON
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thought that came to mind was "Wow !!! You must have rather big transactions."

According to [mysqlperformanceblog.com's Reasons for run-away main Innodb Tablespace](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/06/10/reasons-for-run-away-main-innodb-tablespace/), these are the main issues that cause ibdata1 to grow:

- Lots of Transactional Changes
- Very Long Transactions
- Lagging Purge Thread

The undo logs inside ibdata1 will hold lots of info to support transaction isolation levels. Since you are using `READ-COMMITTED`, this growth can be more significant.

I have discussed this  before in the DBA StackExchange

- `Aug 21, 2015` : [Transactional DDL workflow for MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90794/transactional-ddl-workflow-for-mysql/111874#111874)
- `Jun 16, 2014` : [MySQL Index creation failing on table is full](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68319/mysql-index-creation-failing-on-table-is-full/68326#68326)
- `Apr 23, 2013` : [How can Innodb ibdata1 file grows by 5X even with innodb_file_per_table set?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40730/how-can-innodb-ibdata1-file-grows-by-5x-even-with-innodb-file-per-table-set/40734)
- ... [and more](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A877%20uncontrolled%20)

### SUGGESTION #1

Since you are using MariaDB, please look into configuring the undo logs outside of the system tablespace. Please read the MariaDB docs on [innodb_undo_directory](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_undo_directory) and [innodb_undo_tablespaces](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_undo_tablespaces) and go from there.

### SUGGESTION #2

You may have to mysqldump are your data and load it into a new installation of MariaDB. See my posts in [How do I shrink the innodb file ibdata1 without dumping all databases?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24942/how-do-i-shrink-the-innodb-file-ibdata1-without-dumping-all-databases/24963#24963) for other ideas. Either way, this will take some work !!!

Comment: Very informative answer and clarified the issue. I think I need to restart database to change innodb_undo parameters. but still I have some questions. 1. Is there recommended size of innodb_max_undo_log_size? 2. I'm gonna use mysqldump to export database, do I have to "reinstall MariaDB"? or "just remove ib* files and then reload *.sql files which I exported."

Answer (score 6):

This topic has also been discussed in [MDEV-21952](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-21952). In the upcoming MariaDB Server 10.6.13 release, [MDEV-29593](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-29593) should improve reuse of undo log pages. Starting with MariaDB Server 10.11 (the newest long-term-support release series), thanks to [MDEV-19229](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19229) you can change the value of `innodb_undo_tablespaces` after `SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown=0; SHUTDOWN;`.

Tables that reside in the InnoDB system tablespace should be reported by the following query:

```sql
SELECT name FROM information_schema.innodb_sys_tables WHERE space=0;
```

Last but not least, [MDEV-27734](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27734) set `innodb_change_buffering=none` by default not only because it can make the system tablespace grow uncontrollably, but also because of [various corruption issues](https://fosdem.org/2023/schedule/event/innodb_change_buffer/) that have affected MySQL and MariaDB alike.

Edit:
The recently released MariaDB Server 11.2.1 includes [MDEV-14795](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-14795), which allows the InnoDB system tablespace to be shrunk on startup if `innodb_data_file_path` includes the attribute `:autoshrink`. This could be useful in combination with the two changes in MariaDB Server 11.0: [MDEV-29986](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-29986), which made `innodb_undo_tablespaces=3` the new default, and [MDEV-29694](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-29694), which removed the [InnoDB change buffer](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-change-buffering/).

Answer (score 0):

(Rolando's answer addresses ways for that file to grow; I'll address the question of whether tables are in ibdata1 and you don't realize it.)

Was this always set?  `innodb_file_per_table=ON` -- I ask because it only applies to tables that were created after it is turned ON.

Do `SHOW TABLE STATUS` in each directory.  Observe `Data_free`.  Some likely values you will see:

- 0  -- Small table
- 4M, 5M, 6M, 7M   -- medium or large table
- some number, possibly large, that is repeated for many tables. -- *probably* created with `innodb_file_per_table=OFF`; that is, living in ibdata1.

The above test is inconclusive but relatively quick to do.

There is a version-dependent way to use `information_schema` to discover file-per-table; I don't happen to know the table and column for MariaDB 10.3.